# SQL Server - Group bit patterns of 101 and 11

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the 'bit' column whenever there is a group of consecutive 1's or '101' I want to group those values. For example: 11 is a group. 101 is a group. 110111 is a group. 00100 is NOT a group. Below are some examples:

ex.1:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║  BIT ║ GROUP ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    0 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║    1 ║     2 ║
║  3 ║    1 ║     2 ║
║  4 ║    0 ║     2 ║
║  5 ║    1 ║     2 ║
║  6 ║    0 ║     3 ║
║  7 ║    0 ║     4 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

ex.2:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║  BIT ║ GROUP ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    0 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║    0 ║     2 ║
║  3 ║    1 ║     3 ║
║  4 ║    1 ║     3 ║
║  5 ║    1 ║     3 ║
║  6 ║    0 ║     4 ║
║  7 ║    0 ║     5 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

ex.3:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║  BIT ║ GROUP ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    1 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║    1 ║     1 ║
║  3 ║    0 ║     1 ║
║  4 ║    1 ║     1 ║
║  5 ║    1 ║     1 ║
║  6 ║    1 ║     1 ║
║  7 ║    0 ║     2 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Note: Each row that breaks the pattern has it's own Group.

I am really stuck on this, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Comment: I figured out how to group for consecutive 1's and I know for bit pattern 101 I would need multiple self-joins. I have an attempted solution but it's messy and I wanted to avoid confusing readers. Nevertheless thank you @FreshPrinceOfSO, I will keep this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works:

```
--create table #a (id int,b bit);

--insert #a select 1,0;
--insert #a select 2,0;
--insert #a select 3,1;
--insert #a select 4,1;
--insert #a select 5,1;
--insert #a select 6,0;
--insert #a select 7,0;

--delete #a;

--insert #a select 1,1;
--insert #a select 2,1;
--insert #a select 3,0;
--insert #a select 4,1;
--insert #a select 5,1;
--insert #a select 6,1;
--insert #a select 7,0;


with q as (
    select id,b,b1,b2,b3,newgroup
    from #a a
    outer apply (select p1=b from #a x where x.id=a.id-1) p1
    outer apply (select p2=b from #a x where x.id=a.id-2) p2
    outer apply (select p3=b from #a x where x.id=a.id+1) p3
    cross apply (select b1=isnull(p1,0),b2=isnull(p2,0),b3=isnull(p3,0)) b
    cross apply (select newgroup=case when b=0 then case when b1=0 or b3=0 then 1 else 0 end when b=1 then case when b1=0 and b2=0 then 1 else 0 end end) n
)
select id,b,g
from #a a
cross apply (select g=count(*) from q where q.id<=a.id and newgroup=1) q
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Id, [Bit]
    , case gr
        when 0 then Id - row_number() over(partition by gr order by Id)
        else row_number() over(partition by gr order by Id) end as [Group]
from (
    select Id, b0 as [Bit]
        , case when
               (b0 = 1 and b1 = 1)
            or (b0 = 1 and b1 = 0 and b2 = 1)
            or (b_1 = 1 and b0 = 0 and b1 = 1) then 0 else 1 end as gr
    from (
        select Id+x as Id
            , min(case x when -1 then b end) b_1
            , min(case x when 0 then b end) b0
            , min(case x when 1 then b end) b1
            , min(case x when 2 then b end) b2
        from (
            select Id, cast([Bit] as int) as b
            from MyTable
        ) T
        cross join (values(-1),(0),(1),(2))x(x)
        group by Id+x
        having min(case x when 0 then b end) is not null
    ) T
) T
order by Id
```